# Drag and Drop in calabash-ios?

Tags: ios7, bdd, calabash

How can I do a Drag-and-Drop in **Calabash-ios**?

I tried with record and Playback.
It doesn't work for me.

Is there any other easy way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This example reorders one cell to position of other cell in a table view

```
touch("UILabel marked:'Edit'") // Touchs table edit button
query_from = "UILabel marked:'Label_of_moving_cell' parent UITableViewCell child view child UITableViewCellReorderControl"
query_to = "UILabel marked:'Label_of_destination_cell' parent UITableViewCell child view child UITableViewCellReorderControl"
pan(query_from,query_to,{duration:1})
```